# Use a stream and filter to go through multiple lists and get a string

Tags: java, string, filter, java-stream

I have two lists and two Maps which is showed below:

```
List <String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
List <String> year = new ArrayList<>()


Map<String,Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();


codes = [abc,def];
year = [2000,2001]
map1 = {abc={2000=0,2001=1, },def={2000=0.1,2001=0.3, }}

map2 = { abc={2000=0.1,2001=0.2, }}, def={2000=7.8,2001=5.4 }}
```

Essentially I want to make a string to get it in this format where I go through the unique and year lists make it in this format where the order is based on year like this:

```
String s = abc,2000,0,0.1, def,2000,0.1,7.8, abc,2001,1,0.2  def,2001,0.3,5.4
```

I used double for loop to do it like which makes the runtime slower :

```
for (int i=0; i<codes.size();i++){


for (int j=0;j<year.size();j++){

String s = codes.get(i) + “,” + years.get(j) + “,” + map1.get(codes.get(i).years.get(j)) + “,” + map2.get(codes.get(i).years.get(j))

}


}
```

Is there way where I can avoid using for loop and possibly use a stream and filter to parse the string like I did above?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This code doesn’t make sense out of context, and it’s hard to tell what’s a typo versus a genuine error in the original code.

Comment: @TimMoore is tat better I fixed it

Comment: Thanks, it’s a little bit better, but still not a [mre] in that it’s still incomplete. What’s `unique`, for example? The idea is to include code that readers can copy/paste to run and see the problem.

Comment: Also, the problem itself isn’t very clear: “the runtime seems to be bad”. How bad is “bad”? What would be good?

Comment: @TimMoore mb hopefully thats better

Comment: might not really be all due to using for loops, but due to redundant operations. Why call codes.get(i) when it does not change while j is iterating? extract it to a variable `String code = codes.get(i);` When you already got the value you needed, extract it to a variable, call once, use as many times as you need. `String year = years.get(j);`

Comment: Also your nested for loops contains wrong code, i m suprised it can run.

Comment: @Awin rather than having me or another reader point out typos one by one, maybe try copying and pasting your code into a new file yourself, try to run it, and then fix all of the errors. The first code block is not even valid Java syntax, and I guess it was meant to be a pseudo-code illustration, but other people can’t run pseudo-code! It still isn’t clear what the problem is: the question just says that it’s slow, but how slow? Your example only shows two items in each list, is that what you’re actually running with? Four iterations of a simple loop shouldn’t be very slow.

Comment: In any case, I don’t see anything here that suggests to me that using a stream will improve performance, and I don’t see any relevance at all of using a filter, since this example operates on each element of the nested loop. If your algorithm is inherently O(N*M), hiding the nested loops in a stream won’t make it faster. In general, streams don’t inherently improve performance, all they can do is make it more concise to write algorithms that operate lazily or on an infinite source of data. That doesn’t seem to apply in this case.

Comment: Voting to close due to all the typos making this unreproducible as is.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Essentially I want to make a string to get it in this format where I go through the unique and year lists make it in this format where the order is based on year like this: ..."*

It looks like it's ordered by the *year* first, and then the *code*.

You'll have to iterate on *year* and just check both *map1* and *map2* as you're building the *string*.

```java
Map<String, List<Map<Integer, Number>>> map1
    = Map.of("abc", List.of(Map.of(2000, 0), Map.of(2001, 1)),
             "def", List.of(Map.of(2000, 0.1), Map.of(2001, 0.3)));
Map<String, List<Map<Integer, Number>>> map2
    = Map.of("abc", List.of(Map.of(2000, 0.1), Map.of(2001, 0.2)),
             "def", List.of(Map.of(2000, 7.8), Map.of(2001, 5.4)));

String[] codes = { "abc", "def" };
int[] years = { 2000, 2001 };

for (int year : years) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<Integer, Number>>> entryA : map1.entrySet()) {
        for (Map<Integer, Number> valueA : entryA.getValue()) {
            if (valueA.containsKey(year)) {
                System.out.printf("%s,%d,%s,", entryA.getKey(), year, valueA.get(year));
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<Integer, Number>>> entryB : map2.entrySet()) {
                    if (entryB.getKey().equals(entryA.getKey())) {
                        for (Map<Integer, Number> valueB : entryB.getValue()) {
                            if (valueB.containsKey(year)) {
                                System.out.printf("%s,", valueB.get(year));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Output

```
abc,2000,0,0.1, def,2000,0.1,7.8, abc,2001,1,0.2, def,2001,0.3,5.4,
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
// "abc,2000,0,0.1, def,2000,0.0,7.8, abc,2001,1,0.2, def,2001,0.3,5.4"
String strings = year.stream()
        .flatMap(y -> codes.stream()
                .map(c -> "%s,%s,%s,%s".formatted(
                        c, y, map1.get(c).get(y), map2.get(c).get(y))))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

This streams over the years, and for each year, streams over the codes.  Each year/code combination is delimited with commas.  Finally, each element of the stream is joined into one string with a comma space delimiter.